# Exclude first word from list result

Tags: python

For the below code i am getting the below result:

Code:

import tokenize

with open('C:/Users/sanjsoni/Documents/Python Scripts/query.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = f.readlines()

print(myNames)

for line in myNames:
  if line.startswith("SEL"):
    break
print(line)

for line1 in myNames:
  if line1.startswith("FROM"):
    break
print(line1)

for line2 in myNames:
  if line2.startswith("WHERE"):
    break
print(line2)

RESULT:

QUERY.TXT

['SEL student.studentid, student.name, marks.total_marks\n', 'FROM student , marks \n', 'WHERE student.studentid = marks.studentid AND marks.total_marks >\n', '(SELECT total_marks\n', 'FROM marks\n', "WHERE studentid =  'V002')"]

RESULT of print line1:
SEL student.studentid, student.name, marks.total_marks

RESULT of print line2:
FROM student , marks

RESULT of print line3:
WHERE student.studentid = marks.studentid AND marks.total_marks >

How to remove word SEL , FROM And where from the result and how to remove '>' from the line3 result at the end.
I want like below :

student.studentid, student.name, marks.total_marks
student , marks 
WHERE student.studentid = marks.studentid AND marks.total_marks >

Comment: Please put your code in code section.please provide expected output.

Comment: can you post the content of the file?

Comment: that is really unclear. If english is your problem, you probably should ask the question somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take just only one line from the list, for example, the line contains "SELECT" you should write:

```
sel = [item for item in myl if "SELECT" in item]
print sel
['(SELECT total_marks\n']
```